# PDF.js - How can I get currently visible page(s)?

Tags: pdf.js

At an event that occurs after the PDF is loaded I load in drawings to put on the canvas. I need to know which page(s) are currently rendered so as to get the correct drawings.

How can I detect which page(s) are currently rendered (ie, visible, possibly more than one because of user scrolling between pages)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to achieve it:

```js
function getCurrentPage() {
  let pdfViewer = PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer;
  let pageIndex = pdfViewer.currentPageNumber - 1;
  let pageView = pdfViewer.getPageView(pageIndex); //Give you the pageView object
  let domElement = pdfViewer.getPageView(0).div; // Give you the reference to page dom element
  return pageView;
}
```

Hope this helps